# Issue while using the Following component in React,.The User get's added to the NavBar as if it was me

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, material-ui, mern

Ok, this is gonna be hard to explain, but I have a bug that I don't know how to fix. I have a Follow component, where i make a call to the backend to add the user as a follower/following. The function itself works, but when I change the state of the dynamicUser, that User get's added to my navBar and I can access the Profile. I'm sharing my whole code so maybe any of you guys can point me on what is wrong. Thanks in advance!

Follow component

```
const Follow = ({ userId, user, setUser }) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [follow, setFollow] = useState([]);
  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleFollow = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem(CONST.ACCESS_TOKEN);
    axios
      .put(
        `${CONST.SERVER_URL}${PATHS.USER}/${userId}${PATHS.FOLLOW_USER}`,
        { user },
        { headers: { authorization: accessToken } }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("BASH", response);
        setError(null);
        if (!response.status) {
          return setError(response);
        }

        setUser(response?.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("ERROR", error);
      });
  };

  const handleUnFollow = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem(CONST.ACCESS_TOKEN);
    axios
      .put(
        `${CONST.SERVER_URL}${PATHS.USER}/${userId}${PATHS.UNFOLLOW_USER}`,
        { user },
        { headers: { authorization: accessToken } }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Are you?", response);
        setError(null);
        if (!response.status) {
          return setError(response);
        }
        setUser(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {user.following[0] === userId ? (
        <form onSubmit={handleUnFollow}>
          <Button
            className={classes.unFollow}
            variant="contained"
            color="secondary"
            type="submit"
            startIcon={<PersonAddDisabledIcon />}
          >
            UnFollow
          </Button>
        </form>
      ) : (
        <form onSubmit={handleFollow}>
          <Button
            className={classes.follow}
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            type="submit"
            startIcon={<PersonAddIcon />}
          >
            Follow
          </Button>
        </form>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Parent component

```
const SingleUser = (props) => {
  const { user, setUser } = props;
  const [dynamicUser, setDynamicUser] = useState({});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const classes = useStyles();

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    axios
      .get(`${CONST.SERVER_URL}/users/${props.match.params.userId}`, {
        headers: { authorization: localStorage.getItem(CONST.ACCESS_TOKEN) },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setDynamicUser(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.response);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, [props.match.params.userId]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <LoadingComponent />;
  }
  console.log("DYNAMIC", dynamicUser);
  return (
    <div>
    
        <Grid className={classes.button} raise elevation={3}>
          <Follow userId={dynamicUser._id} user={user} setUser={setUser} />
        </Grid>
)
}
```

Comment: your `SingleUser` component doesnt have a complete function, your return statement doesnt have a closing `)` and the function doesnt have a closing `}` - im assuming this is just a copy paste issue over to stackoverflow, but if its not it is always advised to use a javascript linter like `standardjs` or `eslint`, they will catch lots of small bugs for you

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I didn't paste the whole function, because I thought it was only relevant the part where I call the component.  Still i'll look into it, the function works, but that extra issue with the navBar is that  when the state change i become the user that i'm following

Answer (score 1):

this will likely either solve the issue, or make it clearer from error messages where the issue is

```js
// ...

const Follow = ({ userId, user, setUser }) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [follow, setFollow] = useState([]);
  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleFollow = () => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem(CONST.ACCESS_TOKEN);
        const url = `${CONST.SERVER_URL}${PATHS.USER}/${userId}${PATHS.FOLLOW_USER}`
        const response = await axios.put(url, { user }, { headers: { authorization: accessToken } })
        console.log("BASH", response);
        setError(null);
        if (!response.status) throw response

        setUser(response.data);
        resolve()
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err.response.data)
        console.log("ERROR", err);
        reject(err)
      }
    })
  };

  // try catch blocks are easier to troubleshoot with promises
  const handleUnFollow = () => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem(CONST.ACCESS_TOKEN);
        const url = `${CONST.SERVER_URL}${PATHS.USER}/${userId}${PATHS.UNFOLLOW_USER}`
        const response = await axios.put(url, { user }, { headers: { authorization: accessToken } })
        console.log("Are you?", response);
        if (!response.status) throw response
        
        setError(null);
        setUser(response.data);
        resolve();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        setError(err.response.data);
        reject(err);
      }
    })
  };

  // i made some purely syntactical changes - i've always felt this was
  // more readable in my own code to wite them out this way
  const hasUserId = user.following[0] === userId
  return (
    <div>
      <form
        onSubmit={async e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (hasUserId) {
            await handleUnFollow()
          } else {
            await handleFollow()
          }
        }}
      >
        <Button
          className={hasUserId ? classes.unFollow : classes.follow}
          variant="contained"
          color={hasUserId ? 'secondary' : 'primary'}
          type="submit"
          startIcon={hasUserId ? <PersonAddDisabledIcon /> : <PersonAddIcon />}
        >
          {hasUserId ? 'UnFollow' : 'Follow' }
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```js
const SingleUser = (props) => {
  const { user, setUser } = props;
  const [dynamicUser, setDynamicUser] = useState({});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const classes = useStyles();

  useEffect(() => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const url = `${CONST.SERVER_URL}/users/${props.match.params.userId}`
        const headers = { authorization: localStorage.getItem(CONST.ACCESS_TOKEN) }
        const response = await axios.get(url, { headers })
        setDynamicUser(response.data);
        setIsLoading(false);
        resolve()
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.response.data);
        reject(err)
      }
    })
    // im not sure what this part does, since useEffect is never called
    // however using promises is much easier to troubleshoot bugged out code
  }, [props.match.params.userId]); 

  if (isLoading) {
    return <LoadingComponent />;
  }
  console.log("DYNAMIC", dynamicUser);

  return (
    <div>
      <Grid className={classes.button} raise elevation={3}>
        <Follow userId={dynamicUser._id} user={user} setUser={setUser} />
      </Grid>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, still does, I become the user that i'm trying to follow. i'll share my navBar component  and the route in the backend. But thanks so much for taking the time, i'm a bit lost in here

Answer (score 0):

so I ended up fixing this, and the problem was actually on the backend, cause I was sending the wrong user, but now everything works. I'll still will put my code here cause there seem to be a problem with the unFollow.

```
//follow user
router.put("/:userId/follow", isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.userId);

    const currentUser = await User.findById(req.body.user._id);

    const follow = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      currentUser,
      { $addToSet: { following: user } },
      { new: true }
    );
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user, {
      $addToSet: { followers: currentUser },
    });

    return res.json(follow);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: err });
  }
});

//unFollow the user
router.put("/:userId/unFollow", isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.userId);

    const currentUser = await User.findById(req.body.user._id);

    const follow = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      currentUser,
      { $pull: { following: user } },
      { new: true }
    );
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user, {
      $pull: { followers: currentUser },
    });

    return res.json(follow);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: err });
  }
});
```